# Timer wrapper review

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I used this code in several projects. But I am not sure if it is stable. However on production it is working well, but I want to listen your advices:

```
/// <summary>
/// Standard abstract parent for Timer-powered classes. Has Start|Stop|Pulse events
/// </summary>
public abstract class TimerContainer : IDisposable
{
    protected Timer Timer { get; set; }
    protected TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }

    protected TimerContainer() : this(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) { }

    protected TimerContainer(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        Status = TimerStatus.NotInitialized;
        Timer = new Timer(OnTick, null, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
        Interval = interval;
    }

    protected abstract void OnTick(object sender);

    #region Standard Events
    public event EventHandler OnStart;
    public event EventHandler OnStop;
    public event EventHandler OnPulse;

    public TimerStatus Status { get; protected set; }

    public void Start()
    {
        Timer.Change(TimeSpan.Zero, Interval);
        Status = TimerStatus.Running;

        if (OnStart != null) {
            OnStart(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Status = TimerStatus.Stopped;
        Timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

        if (OnStop != null) {
            OnStop(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    protected void InvokePulse()
    {
        if (OnPulse != null) {
            OnPulse(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    protected bool disposed = false;
    ~TimerContainer()
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }
    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        if (!disposed) {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            disposed = true;
        }
    }
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing) {
            if (Status != TimerStatus.Stopped) {
                Stop();
            }

            if (Timer != null) {
                Timer.Dispose();
                Timer = null;
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
    #endregion
}

/// <summary>
/// Timer status
/// </summary>
public enum TimerStatus
{
    NotInitialized = 0,
    Running = 1,
    Stopped = 2
}
```

Comment: Hi Orif, i loved your code and  i wonder, for what the use of OnPulse ?   should the derived class put the InvokePulse be in OnTick ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing is that the way you're calling the events is not thread-safe:

```
if (OnStop != null) {
    OnStop(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

If the only subscriber to the event unsubscribes between the `null` check and the invoke, you will get a `NullReferenceException`. The correct way is like this:

```
var onStop = OnStop;
if (onStop != null) {
    onStop(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

Or, alternatively, you can make sure that the events are never `null` by adding a subscriber that does nothing:

```
public event EventHandler OnStart = delegate { };
```

That way, you don't have to check for `null` at all. This could hurt performance a bit, but it shouldn't be noticeable (especially since the events most likely won't be invoked more frequently than once every few milliseconds).

Another thing is that your finalizer is completely useless, since you don't have any unmanaged resources. It could make sense if some of the children of this class did have some unmanaged resources, but I think those could have their own fianlizer.

Also, in the usual `Dispose()` pattern, the parameterless `Dispose()` method is not `virtual`. I don't see any reason for it here, having `virtual Dispose(bool)` should be enough.

Comment: Tips about null check and virtual Dispose() is great. But I am not sure on removing Dispose. Anyway, I marked your post as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't say anything about removing `Dispose()`. I meant the finalizer: `~TimerContainer()`. If that's what you meant, why aren't you sure about it?